# Hide a submenu class on a specific page

Tags: joomla

I'm a beginner. I want to hide a submenu class on menu item hover, on a specific page of my site.

e.g. If url is www.mysite.it/login then hide .submenu on login (menu item) hover.

Answer (score 0):

In order to identify the page you are on, it may be easier to output the itemId parameter in the body class, so edit your template main file (typically `/templates/something/index.php`) and find the `<body` tag, then change it like this:

```
<body class="your other classes here <?php  
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;
  echo "pageid-$itemId"
?>"
```

this will render as

```
<body class="your other classes here pageid-1302">
```

then, assuming the page you wish to introduce this fix into has itemId 1302, you can simply use it to target your navigation as required in a custom css rule:

```
body.pageid-1302 nav.main > ul > li:nth-child(3):hover > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  display:none;
}
```

(watch out: this is just an example I have no idea about your classes you have to find the correct path to target only the submenu.
Also, make sure you test with mobile, as sometimes classes are different.

This solution does not use a script; it will work easily if the submenu you wish to hide is a child of the item that's hovered; however you will indeed need a script if the item is elsewhere.  In this case, you'd need to attach a function to the hover event, and act accordingly: assuming jQuery is available:

```
jQuery(function() {
  // now the document is loaded
  jQuery('.firstmenuselector').on('hover',function() {
     // the user hovered the element;
     jQuery('.submenuselector').hide();
  },function() {
     // the user exited the element;
     jQuery('.submenuselector').show();
  });
});
```

Finally, you might want to add a class to the involved menu items, so it will be easier to target with a css or jQuery selectors.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try this solution.